# How to echo a shebang in cmake COMMAND

Tags: linux, bash, cmake

I'm using `cmake` to manage my c++ project on Ubuntu.

In the `CMakeLists.txt`, I want to add a custom target to execute some linux commands, here it is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(MyTest CXX)

add_custom_target(
    cov ALL
    )

add_custom_command(
    TARGET cov
    COMMAND touch xxx
    COMMAND echo -e '#!/bin/bash'>xxx
    )
```

In a word, I want to create a file named `xxx` and redirect the string `#!/bin/bash` into it. However, when I execute `cmake . && make`, I get an error:
`/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string`. Obviously it is because the `#` is regarded as a comment by `cmake` so that this line becomes `COMMAND echo -e '` .

I've also tried like this: `COMMAND bash -c "echo -e '#!/bin/bash>'>xxx"`, but this gave me an empty `xxx`.

Comment: I think it's doing what it should since an unescaped `#` starts a comment in bash

Comment: @infamoustrey, the `#` in the OP's code is quoted (for bash) by being enclosed between single quotes (`'`).  Accordingly, the command works fine when given directly on the Bash command line.

Comment: Tried writing `'\#!/bin/bash'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Obviously it is because the # is regarded as a comment by cmake so that this line becomes COMMAND echo -e ' .

Yes.  So the natural thing to do is to quote (for CMake) the text containing the `#` character ...

```
COMMAND echo -e "'#!/bin/bash'">xxx
```

..., or, my preference, to escape that character:

```
COMMAND echo -e '\#!/bin/bash'>xxx
```

> I've also tried like this: COMMAND bash -c "echo -e '#!/bin/bash'>xxx", but this gave me an empty xxx.

Yes, because the double quotes (`"`) are interpreted and removed by CMake.  The result is equivalent to running this on the command line:

```
bash -c echo -e '#!/bin/bash'>xxx
```

.  The command you're asking bash to run is just `echo`, with no arguments; the rest of the command line is interpreted by bash, not passed to `echo`.

Any way around, you need to appreciate and accommodate the effects of the two (or more) levels of interpretation of the command text, with their various independent requirements for escaping and quoting.