# echoing a shebang to a file

Tags: terminal, echo

I am trying to echo a shebang to a file.

```
vincent@vincent-X751LJ:~$ echo "#!/usr/bin/sh" > file
echo "#/usr/bin/sh" > file
vincent@vincent-X751LJ:~$ cat file
#/usr/bin/sh
```

The "bang" vanishes (even in my history !). Everything looks like I never typed `!`. I have also tried without the double quotes. Same result.

It does not happen if I echo just `#!`

```
vincent@vincent-X751LJ:~$ echo "#!" > file
vincent@vincent-X751LJ:~$ cat file
#!
```

The reason is certainly so simple...

The only reference to a shebang echoing problem is on SO ([How to echo a shebang in cmake COMMAND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57328298/how-to-echo-a-shebang-in-cmake-command)) but the problem is different on my side.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure why this happens exactly, but using single quotes (to disable shell escaping) should remedy this.

Comment: @Alexander: thanks. It works. I did not know simple and double quotes behaved differently.

Comment: It happens because the ! bang character in bash is a signal for a history search.  `echo !3` will echo whatever the 3rd command in the history is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this happens exactly, but using single quotes (to disable shell escaping) should remedy this.

See [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)